# Prove that the series converges and find its value

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{-1^{k-1}}{\pi^{2k}}$$

In the first part of the section the book says that the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k$$ diverges and if any part of a series diverges then the whole series diverges. Given that the top part of my series is very similar to $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} -1^k$$ I have a hard time seeing how this series converges

Comment: This is a standard geometric series with ratio $-\frac 1{\pi}$

Comment: The series converges absolutely since it's geometric, so the original series must converge as well.

Comment: Do I use the ratio test? Take the limits of the top and bottom, this was my worst section when I took calculus II.

Comment: I don't see how taking the limit on the top would converge

Comment: Do you know of the geometric series test?

Comment: Look up the alternating series test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I take issue with the sentence, "If any part of the series diverges then the whole series diverges."  That's a very ill-defined statement.  Notice that

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n-1}$$ and

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}$$

both diverge, but

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

converges.  I don't know how to reformulate that statement so that it makes any kind of sense.

Now for your series:   Both the root and ratio tests are proven using the geometric series test, so I don't think it's quite honest to use either here.  You have a geometric series with common ratio equal to $r= -1/\pi^2$ which has absolute value less than one.  So the series converges.